# Javascript : Performance, Sending A Function Undefined Variables

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

Is there any reason to think one of these methods is better or worse than the other?

```
function func1(x,y,z){
  //do something with x,y,z
}

var x,y;
if (CONDITION){
  var z;
}

// method1
if (z) {
  func1(x,y,z);
}
```

the first method checks for z, then calls x,y,z to a function

```
function func2(x,y,z){
  if (z){
    //do something with x,y,z
  }
}    

var x,y;
if (CONDITION){
  var z;
}

// method2
func2(x,y,z);
```

the second just calls the function with x,y,z knowing z is potentially undefined then checks z

edit ...
in the comments i was able to parse out what else i am asking...
... am i setting myself up for a bad time in the future should the interpreter choose to handle the undefined property differently... meaning is this an exploit, or is being able to send functions undefined variables a feature

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. Method `1` means `func1` is more generic, method `2` means less code duplication if you're following the same pattern over and over

Comment: my concern is more with how javascript will deal with the undefineds... i am confident in the second method's functionality, i am just concerned that i am 'exploiting' the undefined property.  am i causing the interpreter any existential dread by sending one of its functions an variable that has potentially yet to exist? the first method seems more humane...?

Comment: also, am i setting myself up for a bad time in the future should the interpreter choose to handle the undefined property differently... if statements are longstanding standards, so what i mean is this an exploit, or is being able to send functions undefined variables a feature

Comment: there will be no hiccups as long as `z` is `var`d, your `var z;` will be hoisted up out of the `if` and joined with the `var x, y;` when the interpreter reaches the code block, so as it stands, `z` will always be `var`d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my concern is more with how javascript will deal with the undefineds

Consider the following (which is only visible in *strict mode*, hence *IIFE* pattern)

```
// A
(function () {
    "use strict";
    function foo(bar) {console.log('foobard');}
    foo(z);
}()); // ReferenceError: z is not defined

// B
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var z;
    function foo(bar) {console.log('foobard');}
    foo(z);
}()); // foobard

// C
(function () {
    "use strict";
    if (false) {
        var z;
    }
    function foo(bar) {console.log('foobard');}
    foo(z);
}()); // foobard
```

You'll see that even if the `var` is inside the code block of an `if` that never gets it's contents executed, that `var` still gets applies to the names there (they'll be left *undefined* if they were set though). Therefore, worrying about how *JavaScript* will deal with the *undefined* is not a problem in your current pattern, which uses `var` for all the names before trying to reference them.
The parameter names of a *function* can be thought of as like another `var` line before the rest of the function's body, so if a parameter is named, even if *undefined* is passed of the *function* is invoked with fewer arguments than named parameters, they will not cause reference errors.

Comment: i see what you are saying, but reading this though extends the question... i over simplified my code thinking the problem was in the undefined variable... what is really going on is a bit deeper involving objects and functions in the functions...if z is defined in a subordinate function, and then returned as an obj key value pair or ignored, meaning there is an obj, then a function is called, and that object has either z added to it or returned as is, then would your scoping explanation be subverted?

Comment: i guess i'll test it using your formatting... googs led me to resig's article on "use strict"; ... interesting stuff, going to go with the if statement to avoid any potential confusion when looking at the code with older eyes, thanks

Answer (score 2):

if performance is your primary concern, as suggested by the title, I'd expect method 1 to be better. Testing `z` for truthiness is probably less expensive than making a function call, so you avoid the call when `z` is undefined. But if you want to be sure, go to jsperf.com and test it.

Comment: are there any jsperf tutorials, i have had a number of times when i wanted to try out a suite, but the first time i went i was left confused, so i looked for a tut and came up short...

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Its use seemed pretty obvious to me. But 75% of the questions posted here seem to have solutions that should be obvious to any professional programmer -- I guess it doesn't require much experience these days to get a programming job.

Comment: wow, guess i walked into that one?  i work at a hotel, this is fun for me, i am what you would call an amateur, ama from the latin amare meaning to love, and the french agent noun forming suffix -teur  meaning one who does, i do this because i love it and for the love of it, you are right though i probably would have a tough time of it getting a job, and wanting to keep it if i thought all other professionals were like yourself

Comment: you're probably right though about jsperf, i should just jump in until i've got it figured, always looking for easy ways out

Answer (score 0):

The additonnal function call should technically be more expensive in the second example, but I'm guessing that the difference is insignificant.

Also, there's nothing wrong in passing a potentially `undefined` value to a function. It all depends on your use cases. If it makes sense to encapsulate that `undefined` check in the function itself, let it be.

Finally, all variable declarations will be hoisted at the top of their scope even if they appear at other places in the code. Basically, as long as you are only declaring a variable, but not initializing it, there's no difference if you put the declaration in a `if` statement or not.